# Is there an option to view conversations\messages sent by my telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-api

I have just created a bot on telegram. The purpose is to create private conversations with users (each user separately)
With my facebook bot I can go into the Page "Inbox" and watch all conversations. Is there such an option on telegram ? This helps me alot debugging my system.

Comment: Simple hack is to create a group and forward every incoming message with username to a channel. For replying to users can use `/reply @Username <message>`.

Here is a similar project you can refer --> [link](https://github.com/SpEcHiDe/NoPMsBot)

Answer (score 0):

To "watch all conversations" you can store them to database (e.g. csv file, SQLite, Postgresql, MongoDB, or any other depending on your environment). And later you can query for them when you need.

Another option, you can create separate predefined chat with you and bot, where bot will write some logs. Or if you have time - you can develop advanced mechanism that will show history (from database mentioned above) and will have ability to reply directly to that chat by `chat_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I used rocket chat for that. I was creating private room for every user and was adding there the user and the bot (I was doing that via my backend). Then I used rocket chat ui to view the conversations.  Currently, I see they have built-in integration with telegram bots: https://docs.rocket.chat/guides/administrator-guides/integrations/telegram